# Как реализовать загрузку похожих записей в записи WP таким способом?

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

Доброго!
Подскажите как реализовать вот такую подгрузку след. записи, место традиционного вывода похожих?
!!! Речь идет не подзагрузке списка записей в категории/метке а именно в на странице полной записи.
Вот живой [пример](http://www.cosmo.ru/beauty/face/cena-krasoty-skolko-tratyat-na-sebya-prodyuser-kopirayter-shveya-i-uchitelnica/)

Причем нужны нюансы:
С моб. устройств - сайт спросит юзера, подгружать ли статьи автоматом или нет (наверно в целях экономии трафа) 
Подгружаются статьи с той же категории (по принципу похожих)

Answer (score 0):

На сайте-референте осуществляется подгрузка постов через [ajax](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/AJAX) при доскролле.

Берите плагин [Ajax Load More](https://wordpress.org/plugins/ajax-load-more/) и делайте загрузку любых записей.

Никакие вопросы на мобильном сайте задавать не надо, потому что трафик реально расходуется только при прокрутке и загрузке новой записи.